# Won't addChild if i choose an index

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to only addChild of a specific picture when it is selected. I am trying to test adding Child of a specific image(index). But for some reason when the index is [0] it adds child ok but if i set the index as [1] it gives an error Parameter child must be non-null.
When i addChild with index [i] in a loop then it adds all 2 images. 
Wondering why i can't select any index except [0]. Thanks for your time!

```
public var loadedArray1:Array = new Array;
function loadImage1():void {
    for(var i:int = 5; i < somedata.length; i++){
        if(somedata[i]){
            var loader1:Loader = new Loader();
            loader1.load(new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/"+somedata[i]));
        loader1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,  onImageLoaded1);
        }
    }
}

function onImageLoaded1(e:Event):void {

    loadedArray1.push(e.target.content);

    for(var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray1.length; i++){

        _contentHolder1.addChild(loadedArray1[0]);
        addChild(_contentHolder1);
    }

}
//
loadImage1();
```

Edit:

```
What i suppose to do is this but having trouble, getting the index, also putting loading the image with an index. 

loadedArray1.push(e.target.content);

  for(var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray1.length; i++)
  {
      _contentHolder1.addChild(loadedArray1[index]);
      addChild(_contentHolder1);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing:

```
_contentHolder1.addChild(loadedArray1[0]);
```

with:

```
_contentHolder1.addChild( loadedArray1[i] );
```

The for loop in onImageLoaded seems to be a bit pointless, as you keep adding the same elements over and over again.

So actually try replacing:

```
  loadedArray1.push(e.target.content);

  for(var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray1.length; i++)
  {
      _contentHolder1.addChild(loadedArray1[0]);
      addChild(_contentHolder1);
  }
```

with:

```
  loadedArray1.push(e.target.content);
  _contentHolder1.addChild( loadedArray1[loadedArray1.length-1] );

  // Use counter here to only add _contentHolder1 once
  loadedCount++;

  //Assuming that `samedata` is a class member (I can't see the rest of your code)
  if( loadedCount == somedata.length ){ 
      addChild(_contentHolder1);
  }
```

You will need this at the beginning of the class:

```
  private var loadedCount:int = 0;
```

Comment: I just tried it again, it added both of the images. I am thinking it might be treating both images in 1 index...but if i put _contentHolder1.addChild(loadedArray1[0]); it adds the first image with no problem(Just adding the first image), really confused

Comment: I added what i supposed to do in the edit, to load loadedArray[index], but i am having trouble getting the index so i am trying with just putting in a int but also having trouble doing that.

Comment: You got it wrong in the edit again. The for loop is not needed there. onImageLoaded1() will be executed for each image (when each image finished loading)

Comment: Now, does it make sense why?: `Wondering why i can't select any index except [0]` If not, let me know, I will try to explain further.

Comment: You got it wrong in the edit again. The for loop is not needed there. onImageLoaded1() will be executed for each image (when each image finished loading). I have got a feeling that you think that onImageLoaded1() will be exectued once(after all files are loaded).  Now, does it make sense why?: `Wondering why i can't select any index except [0]` If not, let me know, I will try to explain further.

Comment: Hi yes.... i think haha not too sure, i understand the for loop is not needed, but even if i removed the forloop and put [1] in instead of [index] it still does not load the second image tho, i am not sure why does that happen, i just tried it i put [1] but it loads the first image which suppose to be [0]

Comment: You meant the onImageLoaded1() loops until all images are loaded right? So then my for loop isnt needed. But i should be able to select an index for the loadedArray(image) right? As it push the content, but i cant select another.

Comment: `But i should be able to select an index for the loadedArray(image) right?` After the first image is loaded, and onImageLoaded1() runs for the first time, there will be only one element in the array. So there is nothing at loadedArray1[1] yet

Comment: BTW. If you want to loop through all the elements, why not to do it inside if( loadedCount == somedata.length ){ /*here..everything is loaded, loadedArray1 is fully stuffed*/ }

Comment: But it is ok if the somedata does not just contain array regarding the images? Because the somedata starts at 5(i set the for loop to start at 5 as well in loadImage1(). And if i want to just pick to display 1 image with [index], i would have to loop through them first right? And i can set all their visibility to false, but just the one with the [index] to true?

Comment: I have missed the 5, sorry. Yes, then: `if( loadedCount == somedata.length )` should be: `if( loadedCount == somedata.length-5 )`

Comment: I tried changing if( loadedCount == somedata.length-5 )  The first time i click the image, it adds nothing, then when i clicked again it adds all the images overlapping each other. But i only want the image clicked to be added. Not sure why